# How to solve Dashboard showing "[user] is missing the Overall/Administer permission" after jenkins.war upgrade to 2.263.3

Tags: jenkins

I was about to ask this question - but have managed to find a solution.
Adding question anyway in the hope that it might help others.
AND because I was initially scared to do anything with wizard in case jenkins config got wiped .. or something. So despite seeing the wizard I went all around the houses moving config files, editing different settings before finally finding the very easy solution!

Upgrade from jenkins.war 2.263.3 to 2.375.1 gave some trouble.
Jenkins with workflow and pipelines.

PROBLEM:
Dashboard shows "[user] is missing the Overall/Administer permission"
You can actually use menus and see jobs to some extent but various parts of GUI are not working.

SOLUTION:
Try to login as admin user.
Instead of Dashboard showing the jenkins setup wizard was showing.
Click in the wizard to skip setup and get rid of it.
After that Dashboard shows ok for the admin user and also for other users.

Another thing to watch with this jump upgrade - ssl library has changed and jenkins internal .ssh/config had to have some changes to control legacy ssh keys.

Answer (score 0):

Login as admin user.
Instead of Dashboard showing the jenkins setup wizard was showing.

SOLUTION:
Click in the wizard to skip setup and get rid of it.
After that Dashboard shows ok for the admin user and also for other users.